Запомнить результат выполнения функции
У меня есть функция, которая возвращает из БД определенный список значений (перечисление ошибок)
def check():
    conn = create_connection()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = 'select name from errors'

    cursor.execute(query)
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return results

Результат этой функции в дальнейшем обрабатывается (вырезаются ненужные символы)
def qwert():
    results = connect_db.check()
    clear_list = []
    if results:
        for row in results:
            row = str(row)
            cleared_str = re.sub("[(|'|)|,]", "", row)
            clear_list.append(cleared_str)
        output = f'Мы получили значения {clear_list}'
        return output

Далее output просто выводится на экран.
print(qwert())

Функция получения данных из БД вызывается каждую минуту. Соответственно, ошибки, вернувшиеся при первом вызове, будут возвращаться каждый раз, пока их не устранят.
Вопрос: как можно учесть (мб записать куда-то) полученные ранее значения ошибок, и не передавать их дальше на обработку?
Цель: вывести сообщение, что есть вот такие ошибки. Когда они устранены - вывести сообщение о том, что они устранены. Но до тех пор, пока они повторно возвращаются запросом из БД, игнорировать их.

Если список не меняется, можно кэширование использовать, см. примеры с декораторами @cached и @lru_cache: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

Если меняется, то не понятно как вы хотите определить, что список ошибок в базе пустой (ошибки устранены), не запрашивая его из базы. Разве что запрос через exists делать.

@insolor список ошибок, по большей части, в самой БД статичен. условно говоря, вылезло три штуки, и они же и висят. запрос в БД улетает каждую минуту, и, соответственно, каждую минуту эти три ошибки постоянно будут возвращаться. вот я и хочу сделать так, чтобы этими тремя ошибками постоянно не спамить, вывести их один раз. а потом, через n-ное количество запросов к БД, когда они уйдут, вывести сообщение об исправлении. появилась мысль, мб, использовать постоянный список в коде, и результат каждого запроса к БД сравнивать с ним...

может, вам задуматься об использовании какого-нибудь брокера сообщений? типа RabbitMQ или что-то попроще...

@strawdog мне нужен временный мониторинг пары бизнес-процессов, собранный из говна и палок, а-ля "лишь бы работало" =( чтоб закинуть скриптик на сервак, и он там покрутился пару недель, потом удалить его, и забыть как страшный сон

Решил проблему через запись списка ошибок в файл. Далее при каждом вызове функции qwert сравниваю список, вернувшийся из БД, со списком из файла.
Для сравнения списков использовал п.2 и п.5
https://pythonim.ru/list/kak-sravnit-dva-spiska-v-python
